# PixelCNN training error 'keepdims'

Tags: python, numpy, artificial-intelligence

Trying to use PixelCNN I get the following error with these input arguments:

```
C:\Users\cknau\Downloads\pixel-cnn-master\pixel-cnn-master>python train2.py
input args:
 {
    "data_dir":"D:\\PixelCNN\\dataset",
    "save_dir":"D:\\PixelCNN\\samples",
    "data_set":"cifar",
    "save_interval":20,
    "load_params":false,
    "nr_resnet":5,
    "nr_filters":160,
    "nr_logistic_mix":10,
    "resnet_nonlinearity":"concat_elu",
    "class_conditional":false,
    "energy_distance":false,
    "learning_rate":0.001,
    "lr_decay":0.999995,
    "batch_size":16,
    "init_batch_size":16,
    "dropout_p":0.5,
    "max_epochs":5000,
    "nr_gpu":8,
    "polyak_decay":0.9995,
    "num_samples":1,
    "seed":1
}
```

Error:

```
T

raceback (most recent call last):
      File "train2.py", line 120, in <module>
        loss_gen.append(loss_fun(tf.stop_gradient(xs[i]), out))
      File "C:\Users\cknau\Downloads\pixel-cnn-master\pixel-cnn-master\pixel_cnn_pp\nn.py", line 83, in discretized_mix_logistic_loss
        log_probs = tf.reduce_sum(log_probs,3) + log_prob_from_logits(logit_probs)
      File "C:\Users\cknau\Downloads\pixel-cnn-master\pixel-cnn-master\pixel_cnn_pp\nn.py", line 27, in log_prob_from_logits
        m = tf.reduce_max(x, axis, keepdims=True)
    TypeError: reduce_max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

can anyone help me out? I have NumPy 1.13, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess your tensorflow version might not be compatible with Pixelnet
as `keep_dims: Deprecated alias for keepdims.`  as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_max), maybe you have an older version like 0.rxx ,try to upgrade tf or change the keyword from `keepdims to keep_dims`

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with facenet, I have changed the softmax function in detect_face.py file.

The correct code is:

```
@layer
def softmax(self, target, axis, name=None):
        max_axis = tf.reduce_max(target, axis, keep_dims =True)
        target_exp = tf.exp(target-max_axis)
        normalize = tf.reduce_sum(target_exp, axis, keep_dims =True)
        softmax = tf.div(target_exp, normalize, name)
        return softmax
```